# Pass ID from GridView row to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

The first commented line below is working with a hardcoded `ApplicantId`, and all I need is to make it work by passing the current `ApplicantId` column on the same gridrow.

I've tried for many days now, and something like the second commented line does not work for me.
Please help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
DataKeyNames="ApplicantID" >
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<!-- works -->
<asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl="javascript:popUp(3)" Text="Select" Target="_parent"/>

<!-- doesn't work -->
<asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl='"javascript:popUp("<%# + DataBinder.Eval(GridView1.DataItem,"ApplicantId") %> + ")"' Text="View" />

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Frustratingly, I've never been able to get a HyperLinkField to output sensibly when trying to produce a javascript Url. The following, however, will work for you:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:popUp(" + Eval("ApplicantId") + ")" %>'
          Text="View">
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

One thing that might be worth remembering for any time when you're not producing a javascript Url is the `DataNavigateUrlFields` and `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` properties as they allow you to put together the Url in a much cleaner way:

```
<!-- Doesn't work due to "javascript:" target -->
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" DataNavigateUrlFields="ApplicantId"
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:popUp({0})" />
<!-- Does work as targeting a "http://" target -->
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="View 2" DataNavigateUrlFields="ApplicantId" 
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://localhost/popUp/{0}/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

just came across this post
Try this, it will work

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>Require Details ?</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
           <a href='javascript:ShowItemDetail(<%# Eval("Id")%>)'>Yes</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

:)